# Modify / add in JSON file using Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have below JSON

```json
{
    "ServerConfigs": [{
            "Name": "test1",
            "ServerConfig": {
                "HostUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9439",
                "DataUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9809",
                "ResultUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9949"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "test2",
            "ServerConfig": {
                "HostUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9460",
                "DataUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9863",
                "ResultUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9961"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "test4",
            "ServerConfig": {
                "HostUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:8754",
                "DataUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:25778",
                "ResultUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:7312"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add another section named `test3` with similar parameters, but in the middle.
I want to achieve this using Ansible.

Using `set_facts` I am able to append at the end of the file (after the square braces), so I need a different solution

```yaml
- name: append more key/values
  set_fact:
    imported_var: "{{ imported_var | default([]) | combine({ 'hello': 'world' }) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine there are two paths forward: one in which you know, exactly, the insertion position, and one where you merely want the items sorted by their `Name`

### known insertion position

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ server_configs[0:insert_at]
          + [{"Name": "test3", "ServerConfig": {}}]
          + server_configs[insert_at:] }}
      vars:
        # this just makes the expression less verbose
        server_configs: '{{ imported_var.ServerConfigs }}'
        insert_at: 2
```

yielding

```json
    [
        {
            "Name": "test1",
            "ServerConfig": {
                "DataUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9809",
                "HostUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9439",
                "ResultUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9949"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "test2",
            "ServerConfig": {
                "DataUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9863",
                "HostUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9460",
                "ResultUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9961"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "test3",
            "ServerConfig": {}
        },
        {
            "Name": "test4",
            "ServerConfig": {
                "DataUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:25778",
                "HostUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:8754",
                "ResultUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:7312"
            }
        }
    ]
```

### ordered by some key

Here the [`| sort` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#sort) will ensure things are as you wish at the end of that operation, without having to take care about the specific insert position

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ (server_configs + [{"Name": "test3", "ServerConfig": {}}])
          | sort(attribute="Name") }}
      vars:
        server_configs: '{{ imported_var.ServerConfigs }}'
```

yielding the same output as above